# PyAudio installation error Python 3 Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python-3.x, pyaudio

```
pip install PyAudio
```

Throws an error saying:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Preview\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.20.27027\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Please figure this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
this worked for me

[I downloaded pyaudio library form](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#PyAudio)
then in command prompt, I installed pyaudio giving path and downloaded file like

C:\Users\%user%\Downloads>python -m pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

here i am assuming you downloaded pyaudio lib in C:\Users\%user%\Downloads

Comment: Installing Python 3.6.5 instead of 3.7.x solved the problem, anyways thank you so much. 